# VSCode jsconfig.json not working to provide intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a very simple 'jsconfig.json' to provide intellisense to my *.js and *.html (<script>) files.

The ES6 part from 'common.js' works ok, but the code inside "script1.js", "lib/lib1.js" are not recognized by the editor.

It seems that intellisense is not enabled for scripts inside html? Is there any way to check/resolve this?

Here is a copy of my jsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": 
    {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators" : true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
"files": [ "script1.js", "lib/lib1.js" ],
"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

External file intellisense in html script blocks is not supported in VSCode 1.14. We are tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26338